# TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable

Tags: python

In python I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable
```

This happens at the line:

```
sectorcalc[i][2]= ((today[2]/yesterday[2])-1)
```

I couldn't find a good definition of unsubscriptable for python anywhere.

```
for quote in sector[singlestock]:
        i+=1
        if i < len(sector):
            if i==0:
                sectorcalc[i][0]= quote[0]
                sectorcalc[i][2]= 0
                sectorcalc[i][3]= 0
                sectorcalc[i][4]= 0
                sectorcalc[i][5]= 0
                sectorcalc[i][6]= 0
                sectorcalc[i][7]= 0
            else:                    
                yesterday = sector[singlestock-1][i]

                print yesterday                                

                today = quote

                print type(today[2])
                sectorcalc[i][2]= ((today[2]/yesterday[2])-1)
                sectorcalc[i][3]= (today[3]/yesterday[3])-1
                sectorcalc[i][4]= (today[4]/yesterday[4])-1
                sectorcalc[i][5]= (today[5]/yesterday[5])-1 
                sectorcalc[i][6]= (today[6]/yesterday[6])-1
                sectorcalc[i][7]= (today[7]/yesterday[7])-1
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: (As @duffymo suggests:) Unrelated to the error, you should propably add more loops ;)

Comment: One of these is unsubscriptable 1) sectorcalc[i] 2) today , 3) yesterday. You already said today is a list. Check out the others.

Comment: Good point, really just a product of my lack of experience with python not having normal for loops

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The "[2]" in today[2] is called subscript.**

> This usage is possible only if "today"
>   is a sequence type. Native sequence
>   types - List, string, tuple etc

Since you are getting an error - 'int' object is unsubscriptable. It means that "today" is not  a sequence but an int type object.

**You will need to find / debug why "today" or "yesterday" is an int type object when you are expecting a sequence.**

[Edit: to make it clear]

> Error can be in

1. sectorcalc[i]
2. today (Already proved is a list)
3. yesterday

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I print today:['AMGN', datetime.datetime(2009, 1, 5, 0, 0), 59.219999999999999, 59.649999999999999, 58.0, 59.649999999999999, 10940100.0, 59.649999999999999] isn't that a sequence?

Comment: The line before the one that fails (`print type(today[2])`) obviously runs fine and subscripts `today`. So it must be subscriptable.

Comment: @b8b8j: error could be that "today" or "yesterday" is not a sequence. Error is in the line and you will need to determine which one is causing the error.

Comment: @delnan: from the look of it "yesterday" seems unsubscriptable.

Comment: Hmm... That makes sense but when I add this print type(yesterday)
print yesterday[2], I get <type 'list'>, 17.79, and the error is in a line after this?

Answer (score 2):

This is confusing to read:

```
today = quote
```

Is `today = datetime.date.today()`?  Why would a date suddenly refer to a quote?  Should the variable name be `quoteForToday` or something more expressive?  Same for `yesterday`.  Dividing two dates as you do makes no sense to me.

Since this is a `quote`, would `today` and `yesterday` refer to prices or rates on different days?  Names matter - choose them carefully.  You might be the one who has to maintain this six months from now, and you won't remember what they mean, either.

Not that the code you wrote is valid, but I can't see why you wouldn't use a loop.

```
for j in range(2,7):
    sectorcalc[i][j] = (today[j]/yesteday[j])-1
```

instead of

```
        sectorcalc[i][2]= ((today[2]/yesterday[2])-1)
        sectorcalc[i][3]= (today[3]/yesterday[3])-1
        sectorcalc[i][4]= (today[4]/yesterday[4])-1
        sectorcalc[i][5]= (today[5]/yesterday[5])-1 
        sectorcalc[i][6]= (today[6]/yesterday[6])-1
        sectorcalc[i][7]= (today[7]/yesterday[7])-1
```

Comment: another alternative is to use slice assignment: `sectorcalc[i][2:7] = [(t / y) - 1 for t, y in zip(today[2:7], yesterday[2:7])]`, yet another alternative is to replace with a new list (though this will have a slightly different semantic): `sectorcalc[i] = [quote[0], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Answer (score 1):

**How to reproduce that error:**

```
myint = 57
print myint[0]
```

**The people who wrote the compiler said you can't do that in the following way:**

```
TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable
```

**If you want to subscript something, use an array like this:**

```
myint = [ 57, 25 ]
print myint[0]
```

**Which prints:**

```
57
```

**Solution:**

Either promote your int to a list or some other indexed type, or stop subscripting your int.